# IE event for right-click delete on <input> or <textarea>

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, dom-events

What event is fired when you right-click on selected text in an `<input>` or `<textarea>` tag and then click "Delete" in Internet Explorer? (I'm targeting version 9, but if it's good for lower versions too, all the better).

On other browsers , the "input" event appears to work for all text changes through right-click so doing

```
$("textarea").on("input", function() {...});
```

works. IE works for cut and paste, but not delete ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jogjayr/qNgWM/)) although [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input) claims that IE is supported.

Comment: Why downvote? I tried as mentioned in the msdn [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg592978(v=vs.85).aspx). Here is the snippet http://jsbin.com/olujef . It does not work for either backspace or delete.

Comment: I think there are already community additions specifying this bug. Good luck with it!

Comment: @Ravi Broken msdn link. And for backspace and delete, I use the `keyup` event anyway, so it's not a big deal. I just don't want QA at work filing a bug for the one case where it doesn't work on IE, and would like to at least have evidence that it's a known IE bug

Comment: Seriously? Someone downvoted this question? What possible grounds could there be?

Comment: yes someone did, didn't even have the courtesy to revert the downvote. Anyways here is the link again. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg592978(v=vs.85).aspx  , ya there are alternate ways but would have been nice if it had been supported properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ravi has written in the comments above, this is a known issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg592978(v=vs.85).aspx